# Nodejitsu deploy ignored files but still ignore them locally

Tags: node.js, deployment, nodejitsu

I generally understand how the `jitsu deploy` command works and thats fine. Works.

But I have generated files via various processes such as `sass` 'concat' 'uglify' etc that I don't want to check into the project because I feel like they should be generated when you pull the code. Those files are ignored via the `gitignore` file.

My question is how can I have `jitsu deploy` or `npm pack` (which is what jitsu deploy runs by my understanding) not ignore those `.css` and concatted `.js` during the packaging process but still not check them into the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an empty .npmignore file on your app folder and jitsu will upload the files!

Remember that jitsu uses npm deploys, so .gitignore will ignore files for git and npm if there is no .npmignore file defined. So an empty .npmignore file should do the trick ;)

Source: I work for Nodejitsu